# inverse proportional probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, probability-distributions, random-variables

Imagine that we have a series of $n$ positive real numbers $x_1 ,\ldots, x_n$. We want to assign a probability $p_i \in [0,1]$ to each number $x_i$ proportional to its magnitude so that all the probabilities add up to 1 ($\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i=1$). One way to do this is to use the expression: $p_i= x_i/\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j$

The question is: if we want to assign to each number $x_i$ a probability $p_i$ inversely proportional to its magnitude maintaining $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i=1$, how can we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $$p_i=\frac{1/x_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n 1/x_j}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @dreamco9 no prob